# Problems with network shares using Apache on Windows server 2019 Standard

Tags: apache, networking, httpd.conf

I am replacing an old web server running IIS 7 (?) with a new server running XAMPP (Apache 2.4) on a Windows Server 2019 Standard machine. I have a couple of network shares with content I need to display, but I cannot get Apache configured correctly. I am calling one such network folder "eom".

I created a new user specfically to run the Apache service, the user account has network access, and I have the service running as that user. That user (as well as my own user account) has full control/access to the network folder identified below.

I have tried simply identifying the network location with a  block, like this:

```
<Directory "//OLDSERVER/data/eom">
  AllowOverride None
  Allow from All
  Options +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
Alias /eom/ "//OLDSERVER/data/eom"
```

In this case, "/data" is a shared folder. If I try it with the drive letter identified like "//OLDSERVER/c$/data/eom", Apache doesn't like it. It says the path is invalid.

I have also tried creating a symbolic link called "eom" and pointing to the same folder with this command:

```
mklink /D eom \\OLDSERVER\data\eom
```

When I created the symlink, I commented out the  block in the config file. Nothing is working. No matter how I try it, the response I get is "403 **Forbidden** You don't have permission to access this resource."

I have also tried starting the web service as myself, especially when testing the symbolic link, but I always get the same result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

FINALLY figured it out! The steps are (all from the web server):

1. make sure you have access rights to the content you are trying to share
2. find the IP address of the remote server with the needed content

   ping -a \OLDSERVER
3. navigate to your web root folder, in my case "c:\xampp\htdocs".
4. use "mklink" to create a symbolic link:

   mklink /D eom \10.20.30.40\data\eom
5. add  block in your httpd.conf file:

   <Directory "/eom">
   AllowOverride none
   Allow from All
   Options +FollowSymLinks
6. restart Apache

Now you can test. There may be other ways to do it, but this is what has finally worked for me.